# В чём проблема? Java

Tags: java

После того, как я ввёл значение, получил такое сообщение:"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 55 out of bounds for length 55
at programm.main(programm.java:12)"

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class programm
     {
       public static void main (String[] args)
       {
            int j, i;
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          int n = sc.nextInt();
          int[] a = new int[n];
          for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
           {
            a[i] = i + 1;
           }
          System.out.println(a);
          i = 0;
          while (i <= n-1)
           {
               if (a[i] != 0)
               {
            j = i + i;
            while (j<=n)
            {
                a[j] = 0;
                j += i;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i += 1;
        }
    }
   System.out.println(a);
}
```

}

Comment: `Index 55 out of bounds for length 55` - массивы индексируются от 0, то есть массив из 55 элементов индексируется от 0 до 54. Вы пытались получить элемент с индексом 55, которого в массиве нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в этом цикле

```
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
           {
            a[i] = i + 1;
           }
```

Индекс массива начинается с 0, по условию у вас <= n, значит, превышена размерность
Поэтому его нужно просто заменить на `i < n`

Тоже самое касается циклов  `while (i <= n-1)` и  `while (j<=n)`, нужно заменить на `<`

Comment: там дальше ещё 2 цикла с той же проблемой

Comment: А это специально было опущено, зря вы сказали)

Comment: Отыветы по идее должны составляться таким образом, чтобы были полезны не только для того, кто задал вопрос, но и для будущих читалей, у которых будут подобные проблемы. Потому оставлять нерешенные вопросы как загадки не оч хорошо.

Comment: Пожалуй, вы правы, дополнил ответ